# Coloring ACF ggplot Object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce ACFs with a color scheme of my choice.

the forecast package allows me to create ggplot2 graphs of the ACF. I can change just about every aspect of the resulting graph except for the lines of the ACF and the confidence bounds.

Here is sample code and the resulting plot:

```
acf <- forecast::ggAcf(rnorm(100))

acf + ggtitle("Autocorrelation Function (ACF)") + xlab("Lag") + ylab("ACF") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="#5C5D67"),
    axis.title = element_text(colour="#FFFAFF", size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="#FFFAFF", size = 12),    
    axis.text = element_text(colour="#FFFAFF", size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="#FFFAFF", size = 12),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color="#1E1E1E"),
    plot.title = element_text(colour="white"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#1e1e1e")
  )
```

[image]

How do I change the colors of the ACF lines from some thing other than the default black? And how to I change the confidence bounds to something other than the default blue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ggAcf` function is based on `autoplot.acf`.  You can look through that function via `forecast:::autoplot.acf`.  When you do, you'll see that the colors of the segments and horizontal lines are hard-coded within the function, without no option to control them.

To change the colors without making a new function of your own, you can add new layers on top of the original plot using functions from ggplot2.  However, you will need to calculate the confidence intervals "by-hand" using the same formula as in `autoplot.acf`.

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

# Calculate confidence interval limits
ci2 = qnorm((1 + .95)/2)/sqrt(length(rnorm(100)))

# Change line color to green, CI color to purple
ggAcf(rnorm(100)) +
    geom_segment(lineend = "butt", color = "green") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "green") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(ci2, -ci2), color = "purple", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Note that for the "adding layers on top of the previous layers" work-around to look right you need to keep the line types the same as in the original plot.